# The custom model weights are not changing (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, ray

I am trying to train an agent in a racing car simulator. I have built a custom model. I found that the weights are not changing during the training.

I am trying to train an agent in a racing car simulator. I have built a custom model following the instruction [here](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-models.html#custom-models-tensorflow). I use [python API](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-training.html#python-api) showed in the document. I print the weights (by `weights = trainer.workers.foreach_worker(lambda ev: ev.get_policy().get_weights())`) and I found that a large part of weights is not changing.

Custom model:

```py
class AtariNet(Model):
    @override(Model)
    def _build_layers_v2(self, input_dict, num_outputs, options):
        with tf.name_scope("atari_net"):
            conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(input_dict["obs"], 32, 8, 4, activation=tf.nn.relu, padding="valid", name="conv1")
            conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, 64, 4, 2, activation=tf.nn.relu, padding="valid", name="conv2")
            conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv2, 64, 3, 1, activation=tf.nn.relu, padding="valid", name="conv3")
            conv_flatten = tf.layers.flatten(conv3)
            state = tf.layers.dense(conv_flatten, 512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="state")
            act_output = tf.layers.dense(state, num_outputs, name="act_output")
            return act_output, state


    @override(Model)
    def value_function(self):
        val = tf.layers.dense(self.last_layer, 1)
        return tf.reshape(val, [-1])
```

Custom Preprocessor:

```py
class NormalizePreprocessor(Preprocessor):
    @override(Preprocessor)
    def _init_shape(self, obs_space, options):
        return obs_space.shape  # doesn't need to change observation space

    @override(Preprocessor)
    def transform(self, observation):
        scaled = observation * 1. / 255.
        return scaled  # return the preprocessed observation
```

Code for training:

```py
def main(args):
    ray.init()
    ModelCatalog.register_custom_model("atari_net", AtariNet)
    ModelCatalog.register_custom_preprocessor("NormPrep", NormalizePreprocessor)

    config = ppo.DEFAULT_CONFIG.copy()

    config["log_level"] = "DEBUG"

    config["num_gpus"] = 1
    config["num_cpus_for_driver"] = 4
    config["num_workers"] = 2
    config["num_cpus_per_worker"] = 2

    config["model"]["custom_model"] = "atari_net"
    # config["model"]["custom_preprocessor"] = "NormPrep"

    config["clip_actions"] = False

    config["use_gae"] = True
    config["lr"] = 0.1
    config["vf_share_layers"] = True
    config["vf_loss_coeff"] = 0.1
    config["train_batch_size"] = 500
    config["batch_mode"] = "complete_episodes"
    config["lambda"] = 0.95
    # config["kl_coeff"] = 0.0
    config["kl_coeff"] = 0.5
    # config["entropy_coeff"] = 0.0
    config["sample_batch_size"] = 100
    config["entropy_coeff"] = 0.01
    config["sgd_minibatch_size"] = 500
    # config["num_sgd_iter"] = 30
    config["num_sgd_iter"] = 10
    # config["clip_rewards"] = True
    config["observation_filter"] = "NoFilter"

    trainer = ppo.PPOTrainer(config=config, env=<my simulator environment>)
    for i in range(1000):
        # Perform one iteration of training the policy with PPO
        result = trainer.train()
        print(pretty_print(result))
        '''
        policy_weights = trainer.get_policy().get_weights()
        print("&&& policy shape:{}".format(policy_weights.shape))
        print("&&& policy weights:{}".format(policy_weights))
        '''

        weights = trainer.workers.foreach_worker(lambda ev: ev.get_policy().get_weights())
        for n in weights:
            print(n[0:30])
            print(n[5000:5030])
            print(n[-30:])
            print('=' * 20)

        if i % 10 == 0:
            checkpoint = trainer.save()
            print("checkpoint saved at", checkpoint)
```

I found that a large part of the weights is not changing. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. The problem was caused by using the wrong hyper-parameter. The learning rate was too large.

But there's still something weird, the input images don't need to be normalized (value range 0~1) before input. If you normalize the inputs, it will cause the gradients too small.

Maybe rllib uses some kind of preprocessor somewhere, so you don't have to normalize the inputs.